# CodenameOne: How to fix this Nullpointer exception when launching the simulator?

Tags: nullpointerexception, simulator, codenameone

I ran into this error this morning when I tried to run a new App in the simulator and I have not clue why. **There is no stacktrace or anything like that, the picture is the only output there is.**

[image]

I am not doing anything special, I only followed the [tutorial on how to access Webservices](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---connect-to-a-web-service.html) and that happened when I tried to launch it for the first time.

Comment: If you press OK in the console at the bottom of the screen do you see any output?

Comment: try to wrap your start body with try catch, it is possible you are getting the null pointer in the start method.

Comment: may be have you changed anything regarding to theme, like name or something !? better you put some log.p("") as a checkpoint and see how far you are able to run..

Comment: Thank you for your help, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the solution, that it was my eclipse having trouble to start the app besides a running `spring` rest application, that I set up for testing purpose.

Maybe the two plugins don't like each other.